# create a Spark DataFrame from a nested array of struct element?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have read a JSON file into Spark. This file has the following structure:

```
   root
      |-- engagement: struct (nullable = true)
      |    |-- engagementItems: array (nullable = true)
      |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
      |    |    |    |-- availabilityEngagement: struct (nullable = true)
      |    |    |    |    |-- dimapraUnit: struct (nullable = true)
      |    |    |    |    |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
      |    |    |    |    |    |-- constrained: boolean (nullable = true)
      |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
      |    |    |    |    |    |-- label: string (nullable = true)
      |    |    |    |    |    |-- ranking: long (nullable = true)
      |    |    |    |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
      |    |    |    |    |    |-- version: long (nullable = true)
      |    |    |    |    |    |-- visible: boolean (nullable = true)
```

I created a recursive function to flatten the schema with columns that are of nested StructType

```
def flattenSchema(schema: StructType, prefix: String = null):Array[Column]= 
        {
        schema.fields.flatMap(f => {
          val colName = if (prefix == null) f.name else (prefix + "." + f.name)

          f.dataType match {
            case st: StructType => flattenSchema(st, colName)
            case _ => Array(col(colName).alias(colName))
          }
        })
        }

val newDF=SIWINSDF.select(flattenSchema(SIWINSDF.schema):_*)

val secondDF=newDF.toDF(newDF.columns.map(_.replace(".", "_")): _*)
```

How can i flatten the ArrayType that contain nested StructType  for example engagementItems: array (nullable = true)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does the array have a fixed length? If not, what you are trying to do will be complicated... To help us help you, could you provide some sample input and expected output? You could also simplify your question to a minimal schema for which your problem occur.

Comment: if it is `ArrayType` then `explode` action should be perform on `dataframe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you need to manage the case for the `ArrayType` and after convert it into `StructType`. Therefore you can use the the Scala runtime conversion for that.

First I generated the scenario as next (btw it would be very helpful to include this in your question since makes the reproduction of the problem much easier):

```
  case class DimapraUnit(code: String, constrained: Boolean, id: Long, label: String, ranking: Long, _type: String, version: Long, visible: Boolean)
  case class AvailabilityEngagement(dimapraUnit: DimapraUnit)
  case class Element(availabilityEngagement: AvailabilityEngagement)
  case class Engagement(engagementItems: Array[Element])
  case class root(engagement: Engagement)
  def getSchema(): StructType ={
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection
    val schema = ScalaReflection.schemaFor[root].dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]

    schema.printTreeString()
    schema
  }
```

This will print out:

```
root
 |-- engagement: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- engagementItems: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- availabilityEngagement: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- dimapraUnit: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- constrained: boolean (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- label: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- ranking: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- _type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- version: long (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- visible: boolean (nullable = false)
```

Then I modified your function by adding an extra check for the ArrayType and converting it to StructType using `asInstanceOf`:

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.types._  
  def flattenSchema(schema: StructType, prefix: String = null):Array[Column]=
  {
    schema.fields.flatMap(f => {
      val colName = if (prefix == null) f.name else (prefix + "." + f.name)

      f.dataType match {
        case st: StructType => flattenSchema(st, colName)
        case at: ArrayType =>
          val st = at.elementType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
          flattenSchema(st, colName)
        case _ => Array(new Column(colName).alias(colName))
      }
    })
  }
```

And finally the results:

```
val s = getSchema()
val res = flattenSchema(s)

res.foreach(println(_))
```

Output:

```
engagement.engagementItems.availabilityEngagement.dimapraUnit.code AS `engagement.engagementItems.availabilityEngagement.dimapraUnit.code`
engagement.engagementItems.availabilityEngagement.dimapraUnit.constrained AS `engagement.engagementItems.availabilityEngagement.dimapraUnit.constrained`
engagement.engagementItems.availabilityEngagement.dimapraUnit.id AS `engagement.engagementItems.availabilityEngagement.dimapraUnit.id`
engagement.engagementItems.availabilityEngagement.dimapraUnit.label AS `engagement.engagementItems.availabilityEngagement.dimapraUnit.label`
engagement.engagementItems.availabilityEngagement.dimapraUnit.ranking AS `engagement.engagementItems.availabilityEngagement.dimapraUnit.ranking`
engagement.engagementItems.availabilityEngagement.dimapraUnit._type AS `engagement.engagementItems.availabilityEngagement.dimapraUnit._type`
engagement.engagementItems.availabilityEngagement.dimapraUnit.version AS `engagement.engagementItems.availabilityEngagement.dimapraUnit.version`
engagement.engagementItems.availabilityEngagement.dimapraUnit.visible AS `engagement.engagementItems.availabilityEngagement.dimapraUnit.visible`
```

Comment: I prefer a generic code for that i used explode fonction on dataframe. I need to know how can i get ALL names of arrays ?

Comment: Hi @J-kram the answer is based on the question: **How can i flatten the ArrayType that contain nested StructType for example engagementItems: array (nullable = true)** Your version was stopping the process of the inner elements on  engagementItems thus returning the data for the availabilityEngagement. So I changed to be able to handle this case as well in order to reach the last level of dimapraUnit. So that if you try to do `val newDF=SIWINSDF.select(flattenSchema(SIWINSDF.schema):_*)` you will get flattened the dimapraUnit struct. Was not this your question about?

Comment: Hi @Alexandros Biratsis yes it is correct. there alse a explode function on dataframe more easier  val providersDF=SIWINSDF.select(explode(col("engagementItems")).as("collection")).select(col("collection.*"))  to explode all arrays for that i want to get all names of arrays

Comment: Exactly @J-kram, so did my post answers your question or not :)? I am not sure I understood

Comment: Nice @Alexandros Biratsis, my question now is how to get all name of arrays on DataFrame like engagementItems ?

Comment: You mean to get each `element` inside the array?

Comment: the name of the arrays as engagementItems I am tring to use dtypes() Returns all column names and their data types as an array

Comment: So this schema is just for one particular record and there might be other array like engagementItems but with different name?

Comment: Other array that contain other Structs with different name

Comment: This can't exist on the same dataframe, StructType(engagement) can accept only one DataType(engagementItems) at least this was my assumption for the schema that I created! In other words for one dataframe with the above specific schema, engagementItems should always have the same name and not array_column_X. If this is your case this schema is not valid and you need to change it. If would really helpful to provide some data example though because we do a lot of assumptions :) also please let me know if my answer is not relevant to your actual question so to remove it.

Comment: If you have a schema like this:

`val schema = new StructType().add("a", new StructType().add("b", IntegerType))`

with this data:
`{
  "a": {
     "b": 1
  }
}`

this is not the same with this:

`{
  "a": {
     "c": 1
  }
}`

because then you dont know which of `select("a.b")` or `select("a.c")` is correct. This is your case?

Comment: my question is how can i get all names of arrays on dataframe ? Seq(nameArry1,nameArry2........)  I want using explode function

Comment: To GET all names of arrays i am tring to do :

 SIWINSDF.dtypes.foreach(tup => if(tup._2.isInstanceOf[ArrayType]) println(tup._1)) // warning: fruitless type test: a value of type String cannot also be a org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayType

Comment: `df.schema.filter(st => st.dataType.isInstanceOf[ArrayType])` maybe this? I didnt check if it works but should be something similar

Comment: Excatlyval df=SIWINSDF.schema.fields.filter(_.dataType.typeName == "array").toList OR df.schema.filter(st => st.dataType.isInstanceOf[ArrayType]) return List[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField] = List(StructField(... How can i get the name of StructField

Comment: to get the names i am doing df.schema.filter(st => st.dataType.isInstanceOf[ArrayType]).flatMap(_.dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType].fields).map(_.name) it is correct?

Comment: `val arrayFields = df.schema.filter(st => st.dataType.isInstanceOf[ArrayType])` 
   
`val names = arrayFields.map(_.name)` better :)

Comment: Using org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayType
val arrayFields = DF.schema.filter(st => st.dataType.isInstanceOf[ArrayType])
val names = arrayFields.map(_.name)  I get all names of arrays on dataframe thanks :)

Comment: How can i filter only not empty arrays  val arrayFields = df.schema.filter(st => st.dataType.isInstanceOf[ArrayType])  |-- objectiveAttachment: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)